# How do I call for another function?

Tags: python, function, loops

In this program, it calls for an input that is then converted into numbers. I want the input to be directed to `get_number` if the input is alphabetic. If the input is not alphabetic it will return the number how it is.

```py
def main():
    """
    Program will map a telephone number to a letter on the telephone keypad.
    If the character is not a letter, it prints it.
    :return:
    """


    phone_number = input().upper()
    print('Enter a string:',end=' ')

    for counter in range(0, len(phone_number)):
        uppercase_letter = phone_number[counter]

        if uppercase_letter.isalpha():
            get_number(uppercase_letter)

        else:
            return phone_number

def get_number(uppercase_letter):
    """
    :type
    :rtype
    :param uppercase_letter:
    :return:
    """

    alpha_to_num = ''

    if uppercase_letter in "ABC":
        alpha_to_num += '2'

    elif uppercase_letter in "DEF":
        alpha_to_num += '3'

    elif uppercase_letter in "GHI":
        alpha_to_num += '4'

    elif uppercase_letter in "JKL":
        alpha_to_num += '5'

    elif uppercase_letter in "MNO":
        alpha_to_num += '6'

    elif uppercase_letter in "PQRS":
        alpha_to_num += '7'

    elif uppercase_letter in "TUV":
        alpha_to_num += '8'

    elif uppercase_letter in "WXYZ":
        alpha_to_num += '9'

    else:
        alpha_to_num += uppercase_letter

    print(alpha_to_num)
```

Comment: What is your specific problem here? What misbehavior do you observe with your code? Any exmples?

Comment: The code is being run through an autograder. So I am not sure if this will have any effect on it. But I ran it in Pycharm and it still gives me no output.  So I need to know how to call get_number() function in main() so I can run the input in the get_number function.

Comment: When I copy paste your code, add call 'main()' at the end and type in some letters as input, it prints the desired numbers (e.g. "test" -> "8 3 7 8")